# Div with multiple text color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please I want to know how this works just like the stackoverflow. When codes are being displayed, the text display in multiple colors just like in a text editor app.

```
<form action="myForm.php" id="my_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_name"  id="user_name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Please I want to know how its been done. Is it an application added to the site or just coding. If it's a bulky process please I will appreciate helpful clues on how it works but if it's a short process please I need a better explanation

Here, I just screenshot this question and you can see what I mean[image]

Comment: `<div><span style="color:red'>a</span><span style="color:yellow'>a</span><span style="color:green'>a</span></div>`

Comment: What you are looking for is a syntax highlighter like the one I mention in my answer below. A quickly seach on Google by "javascript syntax highlighter" will return you a lot of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done using javascript. I recommend this one https://highlightjs.org/ in "usage" page there is a quick start guide.

Good luck.

--- UPDATE

Here is a simple example how to use it:

Assuming you already added the dependencies files such as `highlighjs.min.js` and a code styling css file into your page, the code bellow should work perfectly.

**The code block**

```
<pre>
    <code class="html">
        <form action="myForm.php" id="my_form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user_name"  id="user_name" />
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </code>
</pre>
```

**Javascript to escape and highlight blocks**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("pre code").each(function () {
        // Escape HTML code
        $(this).html($("<p/>").text($(this).html()).html());

        // Apply highlighting to the block
        hljs.highlightBlock(this);
    });

});
```

The result will be a pretty highlighted code!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evandroprogram/5sgrmsd4/

Comment: Thanks but can it be done in a specific `div` or it would probably affect the whole page?

Comment: In the case of example it applies to the hole page  but you can change it by removing this part `<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>` then call `hljs.highlightBlock($("#myblock"));` to apply only to a specific element.

Comment: The example is very misleading: it makes it look that HTML tags inside `<pre><code>..</code></pre>` will be displayed as is. They won't, this will be rendered as actual form elements, not their code. You have to escape `<` and `>` as `&lt;` and `&gt;` to make them appear on the page as tags.

Comment: I forgot that detail, I'm sorry. I updated with a javascript code that escape and apply the highlight to a block. Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evandroprogram/5sgrmsd4/

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="container">
       <span style="background-color:red">this span is red</span>
       <span style="background-color:green">this span is green</span>
       <span style="background-color:blue">this span is blue</span>
    </div>
```

You can later set height and width properties of the div, can also make it more attractive using gradient effects.